# In Django how display all of the values after the for loop is finished instead of displaying them one by one

Tags: python, django-views

In my django project in the view I call the last 6 values in the column and send them to the template. I then would like to pass into google charts api those 6 values and have a graph. At the moment for some reason I get 6 different graphs.

```
{% for foodbag in foodbags %}
<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=0:|0|1|2|3|4|5|6&chxr=2,0,0&chxs=0,1,676767,10.5,1,l,676767|2,676767,5.5,0,l,676767&chxt=x,y&chs=300x170&cht=bvg&chco=76A4FB&chd=t:{{foodbag.12}},0&chma=0,5|5,5&chdlp=t&chtt=Food+Bags"/>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm not sure how to replace string chd=t:{{foodbag.12}}, with the 6 values I am trying to extract from foodbags. I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do the join in the view, and then pass the joined string into the template.

```
j = u':'.join(unicode(x[12]) for x in foodbags)
```

Comment: I do apologize my python knowledge is limited. I tried your suggestion but I am returning with a graph with no values. 

Here is my view.py: http://pastebin.com/vbDXwpAx

and my main page: http://pastebin.com/fxX7EM7Q

Comment: You'll probably have to replace the `':'` with whatever your chart API uses to separate the values.

Comment: It works Ignacio. Thank you so much for your help :). You have definitely made my day.